# Enabling autocompletion in WebStorm for node.js modules installed via npm

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 5.0.4 to develop a node.js app.

I installed several node modules globally using

```
npm install -g module-name
```

and linked them into the project using

```
npm link module-name
```

Autocompletion does not work for any of the npm installed modules. It only works for core modules (e.g. `http` or `path`).

Furthermore, WebStorm gives a warning "Unresolved function or method xyz" for any of the functions I call from npm installed modules.

How do I make WebStorm autocomplete and generally become aware of the installed modules that I `require`?

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1880

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure if this accounts for your particular situation, however I ran into a similar issue in WebStorm 5.0.4, whereas anything that was required was not auto-completing. I was able to resolve this issue by going into my Project Settings, navigating to JavaScript | Libraries, checking "Node.js Core Modules" and "Node.js Globals", and clicking apply.

Comment: For anyone coming here b/c you Googled 'Enabling autocompletion in WebStorm for node.js' make sure you've done this. It just worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As per the link I posted in the comments, you'll need to add your global npm directory using
  Preferences -> Directories

You can find out where your global directory is by running:

```
> npm ls -g
```

Source: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1880

Comment: I added the global npm global directory to project's Content Root directories but it did not help. I use async module, I have `var async = require('async');` but when I type `async.` the only autocompletion available is `exports` from `index.js` from `node_modules/async`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried invalidating caches? File -> Invalidate Caches. Then restart webstorm

Comment: I have just done Invalidate & Restart. No change in autocompletion. I tried modules `async` and `express`. The only autocomplete option is `exports` from corresponding `index.js` files in `node_modules/async` and `node_modules/express`.

Answer (score 2):

My answer works only on WebStorm 7 onwards:

1. Open the Settings dialog (File | Default Settings) and select JavaScript | Node.js.

   1. Specify the path to Node.js interpreter and the Node.js version will be determined automatically.
   2. Click Configure and then click the ‘Download and Configure’ button to download Node.js sources to the IntelliJ system local folder. A JavaScript library named “Node.js v. Core Library” will be created from the extracted source files of core modules.
   3. Finally define a usage scope for JavaScript library just created. By default the whole project will be added to the usage scope. If that does not work for you, you can tune the usage scope by clicking the ‘Edit usage scope’ hyperlink.

If you need more information, read up on JetBrain's Official Blog on [Attaching the sources of Node.js core modules](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/attaching-the-sources-of-node-js-core-modules/), that should ideally solve your problem, it actually did for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you declare multiple modules with a comma such as:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http= require("http");
```

in the example above sys will only have exports as an auto complete option where as http will work fine. If you do:

```
var sys = require("sys");
var http= require("http");
```

both sys and http will work fine.

Comment: This has been fixed in newer versions